# Set Background Color of QChartView

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtchart

Is it possible to change the background/face color of QBarSeries in pyqtchart? By default background is coming as white, is there any way to change it ?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by background color? Could you place an image that illustrates what you want to get

Comment: @eyllanesc , I have added the chart image. If you see background is white color. Is there any way to change the bg color of chart.

Answer (score 3):

You must set the background color of the QChart using the [`setBackgroundBrush`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchart.html#setBackgroundBrush) method:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush, QColor, QPainter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtChart import QChartView, QPieSeries

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

series = QPieSeries()
series.setHoleSize(0.35)

for l, v in (("ABC", 10), ("PQR", 30), ("XYZ", 60)):
    slice = series.append(l, v)
    slice.setLabelVisible()

view = QChartView()
view.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
view.chart().addSeries(series)
view.chart().setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QColor("salmon")))
view.resize(640, 480)
view.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]